# JSON parsing problems jquery, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a little problem with a test program I wrote with Javascript,Jquery and ajax.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button> Push here </button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').on('click',function(e){
       callPage()
  })
});


function callPage(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://events.restdesc.org/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'json',
        succes: function (response) {
            var data = response;
            console.log("hey");
            console.log(data.title);
        },

        error: function(error){
            console.log("the page was not loaded", error);
        },

    });
}
```

However if I check the network, I see that I got the request, but 
I don't get the the succes, so the console does not log anything.
How is this possible?

Comment: typo in "success"?

Comment: oh no, I have been looking for this for hours, this did not show any errors in webstorm

Comment: @fangio typo in "success" will still create errors even if they're not logged.

Comment: @TyQ.  It did not show anything in my browser, nor in my editor, I had no clue it was a typo, nothing was shown, no errors, no logs, this error drove me nuts ...

Comment: @fangio The typo of "success" isn't an error in a way that webstorm can detect. But "succes" (with a missing "s") is not an attribute `$.ajax` is looking for. It's essentially ignored in this context.

Comment: Where you run this page? On your pc?

Answer (score -1):

Use `.done()` instead success

```
function callPage(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://events.restdesc.org/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'json',


        error: function(error){
            console.log("the page was not loaded", error);
        },

    }).done(function(response) {
              var data = response;
            console.log("hey");
            console.log(data.title);
    });
}
```

Comment: For catching typos in method names, this is actually a much better approach.